# Recursive File Updating

Tags: java, file-io, recursion

I have a method which recursively copies files from one folder to another effectively creating a 1:1 copy. Another twist it should do is only copying files that don't exist at their destination and files which have been modified. Here's code I wrote for this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystemException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

public static void copy(File source, File destination) throws IOException
{
    copy(source, destination, true);
}

private static void copy(File source, File destination, boolean onlyUpdates)
        throws IOException
{
    if (source.isDirectory())
    {
        if (!destination.exists())
        {
            createFolder(destination);
        }

        String[] sourceChildren = source.list();

        for (int sourceChildrenIndex = 0; sourceChildrenIndex < sourceChildren.length; sourceChildrenIndex++)
        {
            File currentSource = new File(source,
                    sourceChildren[sourceChildrenIndex]);
            File currentDestination = new File(destination,
                    sourceChildren[sourceChildrenIndex]);

            copy(currentSource, currentDestination, onlyUpdates);
        }
    } else
    {
        if (onlyUpdates)
        {
            if (isNewer(source, destination) && isDifferent(source, destination))
            {
                copyFile(source, destination);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static boolean isDifferent(File source, File destination)
{
    return source.length() != destination.length();
}

private static boolean isNewer(File source, File destination)
{
    return source.lastModified() > destination.lastModified();
}

private static void copyFile(File source, File destination)
        throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        Files.copy(source.toPath(), destination.toPath(),
                StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (FileSystemException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void createFolder(File destination)
{
    destination.mkdir();
}
```

Now my question is why it doesn't always update the destination folder fully. When I abort the process and start it again later it won't copy some subfolders and files over to the destination. Do you see anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Is it because you are using `onlyUpdates` == true? And those files have already been copied?

Comment: @austinwernli: Yeah, it must have to do with that. Somehow the recursion won't continue when all files/ folders in the current directory have already been copied but subfolders or folders haven't. Not 100% sure about the cause though

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the sizes of the files and not only their timestamps. If your program aborts midflight a partial copy will be left behind.

Comment: Code updated with `isDifferent` method. Does this fix the issue you think or is it just a tip?

Comment: It is a tip. But you misunderstood me. You need to compare **both** timestamp and size.